# Why was BB-8 so eager to go with Rey?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, bb-8, rey

In *The Force Awakens*, Poe gives BB-8 the instruction to go as far away as possible. And BB-8 does. So far, so good.
But then BB-8 meets Rey and is instantly attached to her, and she isn't able to shake him off. In the end, she just gives in and lets him go with her.

But why? What is BB-8's reasoning?
I mean, even much later in the movie, when she takes a walk outside Maz's castle, she finds he's never more than a couple of paces behind her. So, why? What's going on between BB-8 and Rey?

Does he know something we don't?

Comment: What is it with astromechs in general? They are a) incredibly loyal (to a fault, really), b) have force-sensitive levels of precognizance when it comes to figuring out where to go --- *and* whom to trust to get them there...